# Failed to update emulated device list on chrome device mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was working on my project with chrome device mode, yesterday it stop working saying:

> "Failed to update emulated device list. Error: Emulated device is missing required property 'images'"

I tried to clear cache, cookies, site data. it didn't help.
I re-install chrome. it didn't help.

I tried to use incognito mode and it worked.

This is happens on every site I trying to enter device mode.

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

The temporary workaround, [posted by dgozman](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507671#c24), worked for me. Reposting here for convenience:

> 1. Undock your DevTools.
> 2. Press Ctrl+Shift+I (or Cmd+Opt+I) to open DevTools for DevTools.
> 3. In second DevTools, select "inspector-app-iframe(inspector.html)" in context selector at the top of console.
> 4. Execute this code:
>      delete window.localStorage["standardEmulatedDeviceList"];
> 5. Reopen DevTools.

Comment: The real fix was just merged to Chrome 44 so everyone will have it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I just opened an [issue in the tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507671) to help resolve this problem.

If you can, please comment on that issue with your version of Chrome you are using. You may also star the issue (star icon to the far left of the blue box under the search area) to show the issue is affecting you and get updates.

Thank you!